# Use the definition of functional limit to prove...

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definition

I'm kinda stuck on this problem:

> Use the definition of functional limit to prove that the limit as $x\to 0$ of $\frac{x}{|x|}$ does not equal $-1$.

Here is the definition of a functional limit:

> Let $f\colon A \to \Bbb R$, and let $c$ be a limit point of $A$. Then we say that $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = L$ if for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $0 < |x-c| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

I've tried several ways, but none of them worked and I'm not sure what to do. Any help would be great! Detailed answers help me with the material a lot! Thanks in advanced, I really appreciate it!

P.S. I apologize in advanced if the wording and layout funny, I'm still learning editing on this forum. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hints: look at the one sided limits and

$$\frac x{|x|}=\begin{cases}1&,\;\;x>0\\{}\\-1&,\;\;x<0\end{cases}$$

Comment: I know the limit does not exist, its a matter of somehow using the definition (my guess was through negation) to answer the problem...